# WordPress Pagination showing same posts on every page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have been building a website recently and I faced a problem with the pagination. I am getting same posts (portfolio post in this case) on each page. I've been googling around how to solve this but it seems that this problem is individual on each theme.

This is the code from the page template I'm using...

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

    $pag = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_pag', true );
    $per = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_per', true );

    $style = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_style', true );
    $animation = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_anim', true );
    $color = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_color', true );
    $info = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_info', true );

    $ratio = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_ratio', true );
    $r = explode( ':', $ratio );

    $cols = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_cols', true );
    $c = $cols == 'two' ? 648 : ( $cols == 'three' ? 432 : 324 );
    $img_factor = '0';

    $cats = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_cats', true );
    $query_filter = '';
    $filter_output = '<li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">' . __( 'All', 'krown' ) . '</a></li>';
    $show_cats = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_filter', true ) == 'enable-filters' ? true : false;

    if ( ! empty ( $cats ) ) {

        if ( sizeof( $cats ) == 1 ) {
            $show_cats = false;
        }

        foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {

            $filter = get_term_by( 'id', $cat, 'portfolio_category' ); 

            $query_filter .= $filter->slug . ', ';

            $filter_output .= '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".' . $filter->slug . '">' . $filter->name . '</a></li>';

        }

    } else {

        $cats = get_categories( array( 'taxonomy'=>'portfolio_category' ) );

        foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
            $filter_output .= '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".' . $cat->slug . '">' . $cat->name . '</a></li>';
        }

    }

?>

<?php if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_content', true ) == 'content-above' ) {
    the_content(); 
} ?>

<?php if ( $show_cats ) {

    echo '<div id="filter"><ul class="clearfix">' . $filter_output . '</ul></div>';

} ?>

<div id="portfolio-holder" class="clearfix">

    <ul id="portfolio" class="folio-grid cols-<?php echo $cols; ?> style-<?php echo $animation . ' ' . $color; ?> show-<?php echo $info; ?> layout-<?php echo $style; ?> clearfix">

        <?php

        $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1 );

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'portfolio_category' => $query_filter,
            'offset' => 0,
            'posts_per_page' => ( $pag == 'no-pagination' ? -1 : $per ),
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $all_posts = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        $page_id = $post->ID;

        while ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) : $all_posts->the_post();

            $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb, 'full' );

            if ( $thumb == '' ) {
                $img_url = Array( get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/blank_2.gif' );
            }

            $retina = krown_retina();
            $retina_thumb = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'portfolio_retina-thumbnail_thumbnail_id', true );

            if ( $style == 'fixed' ) {

                switch ( $cols ) {

                    case 'two':
                        $img_width = 648;
                        $img_height = ceil( $img_width / $r[0] * $r[1] );
                        break;

                    case 'three':
                        $img_width = 432;
                        $img_height = ceil( $img_width / $r[0] * $r[1] );
                        break;

                    default:
                        $img_width = 324;
                        $img_height = ceil( $img_width / $r[0] * $r[1] );
                        break;

                }

                if ( $retina === 'true' && $retina_thumb != '' ) {

                    $retina_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $retina_thumb, 'full' );
                    $image = aq_resize( $retina_url[0], $img_width*2, $img_height*2, true, false );

                } else {

                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url[0], $img_width, $img_height, true, false ); 

                }

            } else if ( $style == 'masonry' ) {

                $img_factor = 1;
                $img_width = $c;

                if ( $retina === 'true' && $retina_thumb != '' ) {

                    $retina_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $retina_thumb, 'full' );
                    $image = aq_resize( $retina_url[0], $img_width*2, null, false, false );

                } else {

                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url[0], $img_width, null, false, false );

                }  

            } else if ( $style == 'masonry-advanced' ) {

                $img_factor = floor( $img_url[1] / $c );

                $img_width = $img_factor * $c;

                if ( $retina === 'true' && $retina_thumb != '' ) {

                    $retina_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $retina_thumb, 'full' );
                    $image = aq_resize( $retina_url[0], $img_width*2, null, false, false );

                } else {

                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url[0], $img_width, null, false, false );

                }  

            }


        ?>

            <li class="item <?php krown_categories( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category', ' ', 'slug' ); ?>" data-factor="<?php echo $img_factor; ?>">

                <a href="<?php echo get_new_permalink( $page_id, $post->ID, $cats ); ?>">

                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image[2]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />

                    <div class="caption">

                        <div>

                            <div>

                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                                <span class="category"><?php krown_categories( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category' ); ?></span>
                                <span class="excerpt"><?php echo krown_excerpt( 'krown_excerptlength_post' ); ?></span>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </a>

            </li>

        <?php endwhile; 

        ?>

    </ul>

</div>

<?php if ( $pag == 'classic' ) {
    krown_pagination( $all_posts, true );
} else if ( $pag == 'infinte-loading' ) {
    echo '<div class="infinite-barrier"><span class="preloader"></span><p class="end">' . __( 'No More Projects', 'krown' ) . '</p><a id="infinite-link" href="' . next_posts( 0, false ) . '">' . __( 'Load More Projects', 'krown' ) . '</a></div>';
} ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'folio_content', true ) == 'content-below' ) {
    the_content(); 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why the same content is showing in every other pages because you set `offset` to 0 in the portfolio query. You should update your offset `$offset = $per * ($paged-1)` so that every page change would tell `WP_Query` to offset right amount of posts that match current page context.